# Navigating through a grid of panels

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I'm trying to make a little project in C# using a small grid of panels and four direction buttons as shown here:

[image]

But I don't know **how to create an easy navigation system** using those panels. The "character" is just a colored panel. All the panels are named like their coordinates with a  in front of them (p11 to p66) Is there a way to do some kind of function that could take a position of the "character" and color the panel on the same position?

**Example**

```
int coords = 21;

private void Up_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Move(10);
}

Void Move(int coordchange)
{
    pcoords.BackColor = Color.White;
    coords = coords + coordchange
    pcoords.BackColor = Color.Black;
}
```

The `pcoords` part is supposed to be the panel you are currently on. That is the part that I don't know how to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Panels
{
     public Panel[, ] PanelsArray=new Panel[6,6] ;
     int xcoordinate;
     int ycoordinate;
     public Panel CurrentPanel{get{return PanelsArray[xcoordinate,ycoordinate];}
     public void MoveUp()
     {
         BeforeMove();
         if(ycoordinate>0) ycoordinate--;
         OnMove();
     }
     //declare MoveDown, MoveLeft and MoveRight similiarly
     ...
     private void BeforeMove()
     {
         CurrentPanel.BackColor=Color.White;
     }
     private void OnMove()
     {
        CurrentPanel.BackColor=Color.Black;
     }
}
```

Then in the form class

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Panels Panels=new Panels();
    public Form1()
    {
            InitializeComponent();
            Panels.PanelsArray[0,0]=p00;
            PanelsPanelsArray[1,0]=p10;
            Panels.PanelsArray[2,0]=p20;
            //...
            Panels.PanelsArray[5,5]=p55;

    }
...
```

You will probably want to add in code to set the starting colours and coordinates.

Comment: Thank you for the example, but how does this exactly work? I'm kinda new to programming in general so I don't know where to place in my program or what it exactly does. Thanks if you answer.

Comment: @TheFoun The Panels class stores all the Panels in a twodimensional array (Panels). The xcoordinate and Ycoordinate store the x and y coordinates of the current panel. The CurrentPanel property finds the current panel in the array from the x and y coordinates and returns it. The MoveUp function changes the y coordinates, and the beforeMove and OnMove functions make sure the colour of the CurrentPanel is correct. I can't show you how to place it in your code until you show me your full code.

Comment: It's just a basic winforms code with four events for the buttons (I know that I'll have to place the BeforMove, Direction and OnMove functions into the button events.  http://imgur.com/a/onw7j

Comment: @TheFoun. Even so, I'll be able to help you best if you show the winforms (partial) class where you're writing this code.

Comment: @TheFoun. I'll be able to help you best if you show me the piece of code containing the winforms class and event handlers etc.

Comment: I think I'm actually pretty close to making it fork, but in the "public Panel[6, 6] Panels;" the sixes show an error "Array size cannot be specified in a variable declaration" and the Panels in the same line says that it can't be the same name as the class name (So I changed it to Panels1)

Comment: Public Panel[, ] panels1=new Panel[6,6]

Comment: Ok, thank you, that helped, last thing. How do I call the panel class functions from the Button events? when I do Panels.MovUp(); in event Up_Click it says I need a target to the object when the field is non static or something like that.

Comment: You have to create an instance of Panels. So at the top of the class you need Panels Panels = new Panels(). Then you need to initialise the elements of the array to your panels, so Panels.PanelsArray[0,0]=p11 etc

Comment: I know I'm probably getting little annoyingbut this is my code right now https://pastebin.com/LJd5PeRv Where am I supposed to declare the panels? (also I changed the name of the panels from p11-p66 to p00-p55)

Comment: @TheFoun. Added to answer. Hope this helps. If it does, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Still nothing, here is a link to the project https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_NRx7DmdnKiUzhfRUtjaEExemc I don't know what else to do with it.

Comment: Will try taking a look at it later tonight or tomorrow

Comment: Ok. It works now and I can start adding new features. Thank you. I accepted the answer. I would also upvote it but my opvodes aren't publicly visible yet. Also, your last name is the same as my friend. Well, his is slightly changed (It's Halbrštát) but that's because he lives in Czech republic. Anyways, thanks for the help.
EDIT (forgot to add this): Also I had to change the "new Picturebox[5,5];" to "new Picturebox[6,6];" because it was throwing some errors at me, but  I figured it out. ;)

Comment: Glad I could help. I don't know any Czech relatives, but Halberstadt is a town in Germany, so we probably hail from the same place a few generations back. Anyway good luck with your coding!